# find operation in matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am using glpk solver for getting the LP variable values of a minimization problem in xmin. xmin is a vector containing 0, 1 and some fractional values. then I want to get the fractional values among them.

```
frac_value = find (xmin > 0 & xmin < 1)

frac_value_xmin = xmin(frac_value)
```

`frac_value` should give me the positions of fractional values from xmin. `frac_value_xmin` should give me the values.

For some inputs `xmin` just containes `0` and `1` and it shows there is no fractional values. like `xmin= 1  0  -0   1   0`

but for some inputs `xmin` also shows values with only `0` and `1` but like following

Where `xmin =`
`1.00000`
`1.00000`
`0.00000`
`-0.00000`

after the `find` operation it returns `frac_value = 3` and `frac_value_xmin = 2.4652e-32` where it suppose not to return anything.

for some inputs `xmin = 1.0000  0.50000  0.00000  0.50000` then it shows correct output too. for `frac_value = 2   4` and for `frac_value_xmin = 0.50000   0.50000`

I tried with `frac_value = intersect(find(xmin>0), find(xmin<1))` which gave me same type of problem too. I have no idea why this is happening. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a normal behavior, `find` should only return finite integers. Can you produce a minimal exemple with this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `find` for this, you can simply do some logical indexing directly:

```
frac_value_xmin = xmin(xmin>0 & xmin<1);
```

Best,

Comment: but I need the positions too. this is also giving me those wired values where actually the value should be `0.000000000000000`

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

If you do `x > 0 & x < 1` of course you will get values back the values `0.000000000000000` such as `2.4652e-31`. Those are bigger than 0 and smaller than 1. You will need to rethink your computations (you don't give us any details about it) or your comparisons.

Comment: I have added an example problem about the scenario